# How do I get the JSONArray that's already in a JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I can't seem too get the second layer in the JSON Array.
What I want is, to get all the names from the Categories, and then I want to sent the "forums id" trough a intent to an different Activity.
If it helps, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) and I'm getting my JSON array from [here](http://api.facepun.ch/?&action=getforums)

**Part of JSON Array**

```
{
"categories": [{
    "name": "Facepunch",
    "forums": [{
        "id": 6,
        "name": "General Discussion",
        "viewing": 217
    }, {
        "id": 60,
        "name": "Fast Threads",
        "viewing": 188
    }, {
        "id": 64,
        "name": "Videos And Flash Movies and That Kind Of Crap",
        "viewing": 239
    }, {
        "id": 403,
        "name": "Mass Debate",
        "viewing": 9
    }, {
        "id": 396,
        "name": "Sensationalist Headlines",
        "viewing": 455
    }, {
        "id": 51,
        "name": "In The News Node",
        "viewing": 100
    }]
  }]
}
```

Part of my code

```
try {
    // Getting Array of Contacts
categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIES);
forums = json.getJSONArray(TAG_FORUMS); 

// looping through All categories
for(int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++){
    JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);


    // Storing each json item in variable
    String CatName = c.getString(TAG_CATName);

    // Phone number is agin JSON Object
            JSONObject All_forums = forums.getJSONObject(i);
            String forum_id = All_forums.getString(TAG_FORUMS_ID);
            String forum_name = All_forums.getString(TAG_FORUMS_NAME);

        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put(TAG_CATName, CatName);
    map.put(TAG_FORUMS, forum_name);


    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    contactList.add(map);
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the array of forums of one category you have to call

```
forums = c.getJSONArray(TAG_FORUMS);
```

inside your for-loop. Afterwards you can iterate over the forums to get their ids and names.

Code sample:

```
categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIES);
for(int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
    forums = c.getJSONArray(TAG_FORUMS);
    for(int j = 0; j < forums.length(); j++){
        JSONObject f = forums.getJSONObject(j);
        String forum_id = f.getString(TAG_FORUMS_ID);
        String forum_name = f.getString(TAG_FORUMS_NAME);
        …
    }
}
```

Comment: When I make that loop, it seems to only output the last item in the json array (Called Hobbies). Even for the loop inside the first loop.

Comment: Maybe you are storing the values the wrong way? Try to debug by adding a *System.out.println(forum_name)* inside the inner loop.

Comment: I apparently keep overwriting the key "name" when I do the inner loop, when I map the keys in the HashMap.

Comment: And I was thinking, how do I make a second level in a HashMap?

Comment: HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> for example. Key could be the name of the category and the list contains the forums. But this depends much on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the second layer from the category JSONObject.

```
try {
// Getting Array of Contacts
categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIES);

// looping through All categories
for(int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++){
    JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);

    forums = c.getJSONArray(TAG_FORUMS); 

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Gson parser. It very simply and basic usage than Android standart JSON parser. You parsing very basically.

Create class for json object items already in it to object or primitive types.

Comment: Are there any easy to understand tutorials for GSON?

Comment: public String getClasstoJson(YourClass o) throws Exception
 {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  gson.toJson(o);
  return gson.toString();
 }

 public Object getJsontoClass(YourClass o,String json) throws Exception
 {

  Gson gson = new Gson();

  try {
   Object st = o.getClass().newInstance();
   st= gson.fromJson(json.toString(), st.getClass());
   return  st;

  }catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InstantiationException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return null;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    

    **// Getting Array of Contacts
    

    categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIES);
    

    forums = categories.getJSONArray(TAG_FORUMS); 
    


    // looping through All categories
    

    for(int i = 0; i < forums.length(); i++){
    

        JSONObject c = forums.getJSONObject(i);
    

    // your code ....


}**

Answer (score 0):

Simple usage

```
public String getClasstoJson(Object o) throws Exception
{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.toJson(o);
    return gson.toString();
}

public Object getJsontoClass(Object o,String json) throws Exception
{

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {
        Object st = o.getClass().newInstance();
        st= gson.fromJson(json.toString(), st.getClass());
        return  st;

    }catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```